# Modify CSS rule when another one is set

Tags: css, wordpress

My code is set to change the layout of the site through options (simple hide/display, left/right position for the sidebar), using the Wordpress Customizer.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
        'sidebar_display',
        array(
            'default'      => '',
            'section'      => 'layout',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_layout'
        )
    );
$wp_customize->add_control('sidebar_display', array(
  'label'      => __('Sidebar Display', ' '),
  'section'    => 'layout',
  'settings'   => 'sidebar_display',
  'type'       => 'radio',
  'choices'    => array(
    'inline-block'   => 'Display',
    'none'  => 'Hide',
  ),
));
```

css

```
#sidebar-primary {display:  <?php echo $sidebar_display; ?>;}
```

Since images of the main content (not in sidebar) change their dimensions whenever the sidebar is displayed or not, I have an issue with that.
I'm looking for a way to modify a css rule `width:`, whith something that would say "If the sidebar is `display:inline-block`, `.element img {width:76%}`, else `.element img{width:100%}`"

I did some researches and I believe I can achieve this with LESS (?), but is there any other way to do this ?
I'd be glad to have any advice regarding my issue !

Comment: Use JavaScript! BTW How you are displaying sidebar with javascript or on page load?

Comment: How do you define if the sidebar is displayed? `@media queries` or suchlike? You don't need javascript to solve this

Comment: Show your code and we can likely help. Regarding LESS, it can't do more than CSS, it is just a style sheet language that compiles into CSS.

Comment: @Martin The sidebar property `display:inline-block/none` is set through Wordpress Customizer which only changes the sidebar css property. How else can I do if not with javascript ?

Comment: You can only do this with CSS if the sidebar is show with a class (eg `.sidebar.show`). If the WordPress plugin is setting `display: inline-block` directly on the element, the only solution is to edit / hook into the WordPress plugin.

Comment: `.element img {width: <?php echo $sidebar_display == 'inline-block' ? '76%' : '100%' }`

Comment: @pawel thanks this is what I needed, sorry for easy question.

Comment: `<body class="<?php echo $sidebar_display == 'inline-block' ? 'with-sidebar' : 'without-sidebar' } ?>">`
and in the CSS-file
`.with-sidebar .elem img{......}`

this way your styles can be in separate file and cached by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since CSS can't process conditions like this, it is impossible to do it with plain CSS.

JavaScript seems like the right option for you.

It is really easy if you use jQuery a very powerful JavaScript framework jQuery.
The code should looke something like this:

```js
var display = $("#sidebar").css("display");

var percentage;

if(display == "inline-block"){
  
  percentage = "76%";
  
}
else{
  
  percentage = "100%";
  
}
$("#result").css("width",percentage);
$("#result").html("This one is "+percentage);
```

```css
#sidebar{
  
  display: inline-block;
    
}

#result{
  
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  
}


#compare{
  
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  
}
```

```html
<!-- This is the jQuery framework -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="sidebar"></div>

<div id="compare">This one is 100%</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```